# ApplePay 'requiredShippingAddressFields' was deprecated in iOS 11.0

Tags: ios, swift, applepay

What is the latest way to set/activate email, phone, or postalAddress in IOS > 11?

I tried scrolling through the methods and attributes and came up with the following: `paymentRequest.shippingType`

Here is the old way:

`paymentRequest.requiredShippingAddressFields = [.phone, .email, .postalAddress]`

I would like to understand if there is a way to write the code that is easier than the old way and doesn't cause a warning.

Answer (score 0):

It’s been replaced by `requiredShippingContactFields`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpaymentrequest/2865927-requiredshippingcontactfields

Comment: That link didn't provide a working example, so i found this : paymentRequest.requiredShippingAddressFields = PKAddressField.all

Comment: This is the new response...'PKAddressField' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: Use PKContactField and -requiredShippingContactFields / -requiredBillingContactFields

Comment: Got it. Here is the link and the answer in objective c. I had to convert to swift. Apple Pay Programming Guide: Creating Payment Requests: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/ApplePay_Guide/CreateRequest.html

Answer (score 0):

`requiredShippingAddressFields` is deprecated, use `requiredBillingContactFields` instead.

For more info: [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpaymentrequest/1619265-requiredbillingaddressfields#:%7E:text=This%20property%20is%20deprecated.%20Use%20requiredBillingContactFields%20instead.).